# R: Error using recode function to replace blanks with NA in character variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm recoding a selection of character variables, but keep getting an error message when trying to replace blanks with `NA`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(c("gender_1", "gender_2", "a_gender")),
                       funs(recode(., "M" = "Male",
                                   "F" = "Female",
                                   "" = NA_character_)))
```

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Can anyone spot my mistake? I'm sure it's something very obvious...

**EDIT**: code to generate a dataset similar to the one I'm grappling with:

```
gender_1 <- as.character(c('F', '', 'F', 'M'))
gender_2 <- as.character(c('', 'M', 'F', 'M'))
a_gender <- as.character(c('', '', 'F', ''))
df <- data.frame(gender_1, gender_2, a_gender)
```

Comment: can you provide code to create a dataset that allows the problem to be replicated please

Comment: @rg255 - sure, have added!

Comment: a simple base R way to replace the "" with NA would be:  `df[, c("gender_1", "gender_2", "a_gender")][df[, c("gender_1", "gender_2", "a_gender")]==""] <- NA`. Note that if those columns are your only columns, then `df[df==""] <- NA` will work - I assumed your actual data has more variables

Comment: FYI - The error you are getting is because it doesn't like the `""` in your `recode()` - if your missings were `" "` (or any other character) then `recode()` would cope

Answer (score 0):

```r
gender_1 <- as.character(c('F', '', 'F', 'M'))
gender_2 <- as.character(c('', 'M', 'F', 'M'))
a_gender <- as.character(c('', '', 'F', ''))
df <- data.frame(gender_1, gender_2, a_gender)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(.x, "")))
#>   gender_1 gender_2 a_gender
#> 1        F     <NA>     <NA>
#> 2     <NA>        M     <NA>
#> 3        F        F        F
#> 4        M        M     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

or

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = contains("gender"),
    .fns = ~ case_when(.x == "M" ~ "Male",
                       .x == "F" ~ "Female",
                       .x == "" ~ NA_character_)
  ))
#>   gender_1 gender_2 a_gender
#> 1   Female     <NA>     <NA>
#> 2     <NA>     Male     <NA>
#> 3   Female   Female   Female
#> 4     Male     Male     <NA>
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with the code that recodes "M" and "F" as well? Or do they need to be done seperately?

Comment: updated the response